# Why am I seeing email notifications in a different language?

Tags: email-template, case, email-alert, language

For some reason, when an external user/customer updates a support case, the email notification I receive is in a different language.  As far as I know, I haven't explicitly configured Salesforce to use a different language (nor have I configured a custom template with other languages).

For example, I'll get an email with the following subject: `Neue Benachrichtigung  Kundenvorgangskommentar.  Kundenvorgangs-Nr. 000123456789`

I don't mind that this is doing this... I'm just confused on where this is set and what additional languages (if any) are set.  Any thoughts on where/why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think the language of the user that triggers the email determines the language the message will be in.

Comment: @sfdcfox This seems to be the case. I have the same problem and search for a way to make the language of the notification depending to the recipient language? You have any idea? See my question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65717/make-translation-for-task-created-email-depending-on-language-settings-of-recipi

Comment: I'm still confused.  Where is that language set? In the case of a community user responding, would they define that in some preference?  Or is SalesForce dynamically keying off of the actual message body itself?