# Make translation for task created email depending on language settings of recipient

Tags: tasks, translation, language

If you assign a task to an user with e.g. english as language, I would expect the notification email he receives to be in his language.
What I observe is that he gets the notification in the language of the sender.

Example case:

- User A (Language german) creates a Task for user B (Language english).
- User B receives an email in german.
- Changing the language of User A to english, user B gets the notification in english.

Is there a way to make the email translation depending on the recipient of the email instead of the sender? Or am I on the wrong track for this issue?